# Endomorphism rings of MCM Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field (algebraically closed of characteristic not equal to two, if you like) and let $R = k[[t^2, t^{2n+1}]]$. It is well known $R$ has finite type and the MCM (maximal Cohen-Macaulay) modules are given by $M_i := k[[t^2, t^{2(n-i)+1}]]$. I am looking for a reference to the fact that there is a ring isomorphism $\text{End}_R(M_i)\cong k[[t^2, t^{2(n-i)+1}]]$ which sends $f\in k[[t^2, t^{2(n-i)+1}]]$ to $f1_{M_i}$.

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.3445v2.pdf) it is shown that when $n = 1$ (noting in this case $(t^2, t^3)\cong M_1 = k[[t]]$ as $R$-modules) $\text{End}_R(M_1)\cong k[[t]]$ as rings. Now the proof is nontrivial (at least I think it is!) and makes use of the fact that $R$ is Gorenstein.  This fact is also stated in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.2000v2.pdf) in the "Examples" section.